# Rotate iOS Simulator via XCUITest

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcuitest, xcode15

I am trying to rotate the iOS device for my XCUITest for a SwiftUI application on simulator version iOS 17.x. I am able to get the app to rotate but the simulator is not rotating.  Does anyone have advice?

I am using the following:

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["ORIENTATION"] == "landscape" {
        XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .landscapeLeft
 }
```

The Deployment section has the rotation supported:
[image]

***When I run the test, it rotates the application but NOT the iOS simulator window.  It is still in Portrait mode.***
[image]

The Device setting is set to auto rotate:
[image]